# Не могу применить миграцию

Tags: php, база-данных, yii2, миграция

помогите пожалуйста разобраться, при применении миграции `php yii migrate/to m180606_092852_add_secret_key_in_user_table` выходит ошибка:

```
add column secret_key Schema::TYPE_STRING to table pref_user ...Exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Schema::TYPE_STRING' at line 1
The SQL being executed was: ALTER TABLE `pref_user` ADD `secret_key` Schema::TYPE_STRING'

in /var/www/u0498223/public_html/coinfactory.pw/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Schema.php:664

Error Info:
Array
(
[0] => 42000
[1] => 1064
[2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Schema::TYPE_STRING' at line 1
)

Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/u0498223/public_html/coinfactory.pw/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php(1263): yii\db\Schema->convertException(Object(PDOException), 'ALTER TABLE `pr...')
#1 /var/www/u0498223/public_html/coinfactory.pw/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php(1075): yii\db\Command->internalExecute('ALTER TABLE `pr...')
#2 /var/www/u0498223/public_html/coinfactory.pw/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Migration.php(377): yii\db\Command->execute()
#3 /var/www/u0498223/public_html/coinfactory.pw/migrations/m180606_092852_add_secret_key_in_user_table.php(16): yii\db\Migration->addColumn('pref_user', 'secret_key', 'Schema::TYPE_ST...')
#4 /var/www/u0498223/public_html/coinfactory.pw/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/controllers/BaseMigrateController.php(725): m180606_092852_add_secret_key_in_user_table->up()
#5 /var/www/u0498223/public_html/coinfactory.pw/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/controllers/BaseMigrateController.php(199): yii\console\controllers\BaseMigrateController->migrateUp('m180606_092852_...')
#6 /var/www/u0498223/public_html/coinfactory.pw/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/controllers/BaseMigrateController.php(845): yii\console\controllers\BaseMigrateController->actionUp(1)
#7 /var/www/u0498223/public_html/coinfactory.pw/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/controllers/BaseMigrateController.php(369): yii\console\controllers\BaseMigrateController->migrateToVersion('m180606_092852')
#8 [internal function]: yii\console\controllers\BaseMigrateController->actionTo('m180606_092852_...')
#9 /var/www/u0498223/public_html/coinfactory.pw/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#10 /var/www/u0498223/public_html/coinfactory.pw/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(157): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#11 /var/www/u0498223/public_html/coinfactory.pw/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Controller.php(148): yii\base\Controller->runAction('to', Array)
#12 /var/www/u0498223/public_html/coinfactory.pw/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(528): yii\console\Controller->runAction('to', Array)
#13 /var/www/u0498223/public_html/coinfactory.pw/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(180): yii\base\Module->runAction('migrate/to', Array)
#14 /var/www/u0498223/public_html/coinfactory.pw/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(147): yii\console\Application->runAction('migrate/to', Array)
#15 /var/www/u0498223/public_html/coinfactory.pw/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): yii\console\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\console\Request))
#16 /var/www/u0498223/public_html/coinfactory.pw/yii(20): yii\base\Application->run()
#17 {main}
```

Я добавила в таблицу `user` колонку `secret_key` таким образом:

```
<?php

use yii\db\Migration;
use yii\db\Schema;

class m180606_092852_add_secret_key_in_user_table extends Migration
{
    // Use up()/down() to run migration code without a transaction.
    public function up()
    {
        $this->addColumn('{{%user}}', 'secret_key', 'Schema::TYPE_STRING');
    }

    public function down()
    {
        $this->dropColumn('{{%user}}', 'secret_key');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решён! Нужно было убрать кавычки в классе Schema. Результат:

```
<?php

use yii\db\Migration;
use yii\db\Schema;

class m180606_092852_add_secret_key_in_user_table extends Migration
{
    // Use up()/down() to run migration code without a transaction.
    public function up()
    {
        $this->addColumn('{{%user}}', 'secret_key', Schema::TYPE_STRING);
    }

    public function down()
    {
        $this->dropColumn('{{%user}}', 'secret_key');
    }

}
```